# Кликабельность ссылки на блоке css

Tags: css, css3

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать ссылку на блоке кликабельной? Думаю, что проблема в свойстве z-index, но почему-то исправить не получается. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```css
.test img{
 width:100%;
 transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
 position:relative;
 z-index:2;
}
.view a{
 z-index:3;
}
.test img:hover {
 opacity:0.1;
 cursor:pointer;
 transform: scale(2) rotate(10deg); 
}
.test {
 overflow:hidden;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 height:200px;
 margin-bottom:15px;
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
}
.view {
 position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; cursor:pointer; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1); z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="span12 test">
<img src="https://pp.vk.me/c615817/v615817671/19ee1/_QYeeox-ysU.jpg" alt="Core Values">
  <div class="view">
   <a href="http://www.google.ru">Ссылка на блоке</a>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="http://www.google.ru">Ссылка вне блока</a>
```

Comment: @Geyan да нет же, по клику на ссылку переход на Гугл не происходит (по крайней мере у меня так, браузер Хром)

Comment: @Geyan Чувак, тут суть не в этом, как написана ссылка. Вне блока она кликабельная. На блоке - нет.
п.с. добавление www ничего и не даёт

Comment: @Geyan ничего не изменилось

Comment: @Geyan не совсем... при наведении на ссылку, эффект поворота картинки должен остаться

Comment: @Geyan если не составит труда, сделай, пожалуйста
а я пока попробую через немного другой алгоритм

Comment: проверь http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/AXVBAB?editors=1010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Проблема была в `z-index` и размере блоков**

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  line-height:1;
  transition:.5s;
}
.block,img{
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.block{
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
 .block img:hover{
  transform:rotate(10deg);
  transform:scale(1.5)rotate(-16deg);
}
.div1{
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  z-index:2;
}
.div1 a{
  display:block;
  width:40%;
  text-align:center;
  padding:15px 20px;
}
.block:hover .div1 a,
.div1 a:hover{
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.3);
  color:#fefefe;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"> 
  <img src="http://wallpapertvs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/dreamy_child_girl-wallpaper-1920x1200.jpg" alt="" />
<div class="div1"> 
  <a href="http://google.kz">Любимый гугл</a>
</div>
<div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```